# Swift Increment through Enum

Tags: swift, enums

I love that Swift allows for the use of enum methods.  I'm trying to work with a method but am looking for a more extensible method of doing this:

```
enum CopyState{
    case binary, hex, both
    init(){
        self = .both
    }
    mutating func next() {
        if self == .binary{
            self = .hex
        } else if self == .hex {
            self = .both
        } else if self == .both{
            self = .binary
        }
    }
}

var state = CopyState()

state.next()
```

I'd like to essentially cast the enum to an integer and increment it modulo the number of total enum options

Adding or removing enum options is a hassle (I'm using a last() and a next() method).

Comment: If you are looking for options, an `OptionSet` would be probably a better solution.

Comment: [how to increment a swift int enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366710/how-to-increment-a-swift-int-enumeration) is very close to what you want.

Comment: yes, I found that on a search, but... it doesn't have a way to increment modulo the number of enumerations (i.e. wrap on "both" in my example).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update** Starting with Swift 4.2 you can make use of the newly added support `CaseIterable` protocol, which adds compiler support for generating a list of all cases for an enum. Though @ninestones's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48612076/swift-increment-through-enum/48612152#comment108080020_48612152) pointed put that we are not guaranteed for `allCases` to return the cases in the same order as defined, the synthesized implementation does this, and it's unlikely that definition will change.

Your enum could then look something like this (no more hardcoded start value):

```
enum CopyState: CaseIterable {
    case binary, hex, both

    mutating func next() {
        let allCases = type(of: self).allCases
        self = allCases[(allCases.index(of: self)! + 1) % allCases.count]
    }
}
```

You can make this piece of functionality available to all `CaseIterable` enums:

```swift
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    mutating func next() {
        let allCases = Self.allCases
        // just a sanity check, as the possibility of a enum case to not be
        // present in `allCases` is quite low
        guard let selfIndex = allCases.index(of: self) else { return }
        let nextIndex = Self.allCases.index(after: selfIndex)
        self = allCases[nextIndex == allCases.endIndex ? allCases.startIndex : nextIndex]
    }
}

enum CopyState: CaseIterable {
    case binary, hex, both
}

var state = CopyState.hex
state.next()
print(state) // both
state.next()
print(state) // binary
```

Or, a little bit more verbose, but with a better separation of concerns:

```
extension Collection {
    // adding support for computing indexes in a circular fashion
    func circularIndex(after i: Index) -> Index {
        let nextIndex = index(after: i)
        return nextIndex == endIndex ? startIndex : nextIndex
    }
}

extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    // adding support for retrieving the next element in a circular fashion
    func circularElement(after element: Element) -> Element? {
        return index(of: element).map { self[circularIndex(after: $0)] }
    }
}

// Protocol to allow iterating in place (similar to a type conforming to both Sequence and IteratorProtocol)
protocol InPlaceIterable {
    mutating func next()
}

extension InPlaceIterable where Self: CaseIterable, Self: Equatable {
    // adding default implementation for enums
    mutating func next() {
        self = type(of: self).allCases.circularElement(after: self)!
    }
}

// now the enums need only the protocol conformances, they get the
// functionalities for free
enum CopyState: CaseIterable, InPlaceIterable {
    case binary, hex, both
}
```

---

You could use `Int` as raw value for your enum (note that this is also the default raw value if you don't specify it), and use it like this:

```
enum CopyState: Int {
    case binary, hex, both

    mutating func next(){
        self = CopyState(rawValue: rawValue + 1) ?? .binary
    }
}

var state = CopyState.hex
state.next()
print(state) // both
state.next()
print(state) // binary
```

This works fine as long as you have the raw values of the enum cases in consecutive order. By default the compiler assigns consecutive raw values.

You'd also need to keep in mind to update the `next()` method if the first case changes, otherwise it will no longer correctly work.

An alternative to the above limitation, suggested by @MartinR, is to force unwrap the raw value zero:

```
mutating func next(){
    self = CopyState(rawValue: rawValue + 1) ?? CopyState(rawValue: 0)!
}
```

The above code won't require updating the method when the first enum case changes, however it has the potential of crashing the app if the starting raw value of the enum changes.

Comment: This code needs to wrap the rawValue so `both` goes to `binary`. And `next` shouldn't return an optional.

Comment: "an enum cannot have mutating methods" then why does my posted example work?

Comment: Or `return CopyState(rawValue: rawValue + 1) ?? CopyState(rawValue: 0)!` to avoid "hard-coding" the first enum case.

Comment: @MartinR exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Cristik There's nothing wrong with `!` when you use it properly.

Comment: Using `rawValue` is a good option, but fails if you assign your own non-`Int` raw values, like strings.

Comment: @Zonker.in.Geneva agreed, Swift 4.2 anyway has a more robust solution via `CaseIterable`

Comment: @Jim_from_Princeton, @Zonker.in.Geneva, @Cristik: I would not rely on `CaseIterable` here. `CaseIterable` only states to return a collection of all enum values and does not make any guarantee about the order. The fact, that it does return the cases in the coded order is an implementation detail and may change. Also, your code would be more explicit if you used an `Int` backed enum and declared the cases explicitly stating their order like : `case binary = 0; case hex = 1; case both = 2`. The rest is stated finely in Crisk's answer. Just pick the Int-backed solution!

Comment: @ninestones valid point, however I doubt that Apple will change the synthesized implementation, and since the enum we query is under our control it's unlikely that we'll not be using the synthesized implementation. But I will add a disclaimer to the answer, thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 3):

Swift [doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) says

> When you’re working with enumerations that store integer or string raw
>   values, you don’t have to explicitly assign a raw value for each case.
>   When you don’t, Swift automatically assigns the values for you.
>
> For example, when integers are used for raw values, the implicit value
>   for each case is one more than the previous case. If the first case
>   doesn’t have a value set, its value is 0.

So this is safe (Swift5)

```
enum CopyState: Int {
    case binary, hex, both

    mutating func next(){
        self = CopyState(rawValue: rawValue + 1) ?? CopyState(rawValue: 0)!
    }
}
```

Comment: I realise this is basically Cristik's answer as refined by Martin R but wanted to include the docs to reassure people that the assumption of values is safe for an Int enum.

Answer (score 3):

If someone is interested in both `previous()` and `next()` cases and more generic cyclic offset function like `advanced(by n: Int)`:

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    
    func previous() -> Self {
        let all = Self.allCases
        var idx = all.firstIndex(of: self)!
        if idx == all.startIndex {
            let lastIndex = all.index(all.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
            return all[lastIndex]
        } else {
            all.formIndex(&idx, offsetBy: -1)
            return all[idx]
        }
    }

    func next() -> Self {
        let all = Self.allCases
        let idx = all.firstIndex(of: self)!
        let next = all.index(after: idx)
        return all[next == all.endIndex ? all.startIndex : next]
    }

    func advanced(by n: Int) -> Self {
        let all = Array(Self.allCases)
        let idx = (all.firstIndex(of: self)! + n) % all.count
        if idx >= 0 {
            return all[idx]
        } else {
            return all[all.count + idx]
        }
    }
    
}
```

Usage:

```
let s = CopyState.hex.advanced(by: -4)
print(s) // binary
```

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 1):

## 2020

Just FTR here's @Cristik awesome answer, latest syntax:

```
enum Fruits: CaseIterable {
    case apple, banana, pitahaya, cherry
    
    mutating func loopme() {
        let a = type(of: self).allCases
        self = a[(a.firstIndex(of: self)! + 1) % a.count]
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, you can use `Self` instead of `type(of: self)`

Comment: really, I did not know that !

Answer (score 1):

I would not rely on `CaseIterable` here. CaseIterable only states to return a collection of all enum values and does not make any guarantee about the order.

The fact, that it does return the cases in the coded order is an implementation detail and may change w/o breaking Protocol conformance.

However, I would assign int values to the cases explicitly:

- Your code states that you want an order.
- You help your team mates to not just change the order of implicitly assigned cases and break your `next()` logic.

Closest is @Cristik 's `Int` backed enum.

```
enum CopyState: Int {
  case binary = 0
  case hex = 1
  case both = 2
  mutating func next() {
    self = CopyState(rawValue: rawValue + 1) ?? .binary // or what ever should be the default
  }
}
```

Comment: I like that you're trying to be safe, but there is no way the auto-generated case order is going to change.

Comment: @Jessy, Maybe with iOS 14, the compiler generation code is refactored? Also, you are missing on my second point: Coding the desired order explicitly to help your teammates not to change the order.

Answer (score 0):

What you've got here is a "circular case sequence". You can make that!

By doing so, you can start with just this, as you had…

```swift
enum CopyState {
  case binary, hex, both

  init() { self = .both }
}
```

…and be able to do stuff like this:

```swift
var state = CopyState()
state.next() // binary
state.offset(by: -2) // hex
CopyState.allCases.elementsEqual( CopyState().prefix(3) )  // true
```

In reverse order of how you'd write the required pieces:

1. Adopt the protocol.

```swift
extension CopyState: CircularCaseSequence { }
```

2. Declare the protocol.

```swift
public protocol CircularCaseSequence:
  CaseIterable, Sequence, IteratorProtocol, Equatable
{ }
```

Note the `CaseIterable` there. Even if `CopyState` is `RawRepresentable`, as shown in other answers, it should still be `CaseIterable`.

3. Conform to `Sequence`.

```swift
public extension CircularCaseSequence {
  mutating func next() -> Self? {
    self = offset(by: 1)
    return self
  }
}
```

4. Allow cases to be offset.

```swift
public extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
  /// Another case from `allCases`.
  ///
  /// Circularly wraps `offset` to always provide an element,
  /// even when the resulting `index` is not valid.
  func offset(by offset: Int) -> Self {
    Self.allCases[self, moduloOffset: offset]!
  }
}
```

5. Allow `Collection` elements to be offset.

```swift
public extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
  /// Circularly wraps `index`, to always provide an element,
  /// even when `index` is not valid.
  subscript(
    _ element: Element,
    moduloOffset offset: Int
  ) -> Element? {
    firstIndex(of: element).map {
      self[modulo: index($0, offsetBy: offset)]
    }
  }
}
```

6. Allow `Collection` indices to be wrapped.

```swift
public extension Collection {
  /// Circularly wraps `index`, to always provide an element,
  /// even when `index` is not valid.
  subscript(modulo index: Index) -> Element {
    self[
      self.index(
        startIndex,
        offsetBy:
          distance(from: startIndex, to: index)
          .modulo(count)
      )
    ]
  }
}
```

7. Define modulo.

```swift
public extension BinaryInteger {
  func modulo(_ divisor: Self) -> Self {
    let remainder = self % divisor
    return
      remainder >= 0
      ? remainder
      : remainder + divisor
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Something I sometimes do is create a simple dictionary like this:

```
let copyStateDictionary = [
    CopyState.binary: CopyState.hex,
    CopyState.hex: CopyState.both,
    CopyState.both: CopyState.binary
]
```

Then you can "increment" your variable with:

```
state = copyStateDictionary[state]
```

There might be a programmatic way of generating this dictionary, rather than hard-coding it, but if it's just 3-4 values, hard-coding is OK.

Comment: This is a very inefficient way of doing it compared to the other solutions, which is why you got downvoted. Dictionaries are relatively expensive compare to some int incrementing and value checks.

Comment: My comment on my own reply was deleted? Proof positive of what I said in the deleted post. smh