# How to get next case of enum(i.e. write a circulating method) in Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, enums

Swift 4.2 introduces a new `CaseIterable` protocol that automatically generates an array property of all cases in an enum.
Now I want to implement a default method for Enum inherits from `CaseIterable` that can return the next case of a giving case. If this case is the last case, return the first case. Like a circle.
If I write this for specific Enum, it works correctly:

```
enum Direction: CaseIterable {
  case east, south, west, north

  func next() -> Direction {
    let all = type(of: self).allCases // 1
    if self == all.last! {
      return all.first!
    } else {
      let index = all.firstIndex(of: self)!
      return all[index + 1]
    }
  }
}

print(Direction.east.next()) // south  
print(Direction.north.next()) // east
```

But I want to implement this function to many Enum. Copying and pasting code repeatedly are not good (Not to mention this code is totally the same for every Enum).
So I tried this. But something went wrong.
(I suggest you copy following code to playground that you can understand this problem more quickly):

```
extension CaseIterable {
  func next() -> Self {
    let all = type(of: self).allCases // 1
    if self == all.last { // 2
      return all.first!
    } else {
      let index = all.firstIndex { (ele) -> Bool in
        self == ele // 3
      }
      return all[index + 1]
    }
  }
}
```

Three points:

1. `all`'s type is `Self.AllCases`, which is a `Collection` type. But in the method above, it's `[Direction]`.
2. There's an error at line 2 says `Value of type 'Self.AllCases' has no member 'last'`
   (Even I avoid to use `last`, the error at line 3 can't be avoided.)
3. At line 3, the error is `Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Self' operands`

And even I use generic constraints, it's the same.

```
func next<T: CaseIterable>(element: T) -> T {...}
```

Any solutions? :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48612076/1974224

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Some problems with your approach are:

- The `Collection` protocol does not define a `last` property.
- In order to compare the elements with `==` they have to be `Equatable`.
- Collection indices are not necessarily integers, they must be incremented
  with `index(after:)`.

This seems to be a working solution (tested with Xcode 10.0 beta 2):

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    func next() -> Self {
        let all = Self.allCases
        let idx = all.firstIndex(of: self)!
        let next = all.index(after: idx)
        return all[next == all.endIndex ? all.startIndex : next]
    }
}
```

*Example:*

```
enum Direction: CaseIterable {
    case east, south, west, north
}

print(Direction.east.next()) // south
print(Direction.north.next()) // east
```

*Remarks:*

- Only enumerations without associated values are `CaseIterable`, and
  those are also `Equatable` (but the compiler does not figure out that
  by itself). Therefore `Self: Equatable` is not a
  real restriction.
- `Self.allCases` can be used in Swift 4.2 to access the type property
  from an instance method.
- The forced unwrapping is safe because we *know* that the value is
  an element of `allCases`.
- Your `enum Direction: CaseIterable` compiles because the concrete
  `enum Direction` type is `Equatable`, and its `Direction.allCases` is an `Array` – which has integer indices and a `last` property.

Comment: It works perfectly! I forgot Enum is not `Equatable` by default. and `AllCases.Element` is also a point hard to catch. Thank you so much!

Comment: @usako_lynn: Actually that can be simplified to `Self.Equatable` – I have added some explanations.

Answer (score 19):

If someone is interested into both `previous` and `next` cases, here's an upgrade of the previous answer:

```swift
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable, AllCases: BidirectionalCollection {
    func previous() -> Self {
        let all = Self.allCases
        let idx = all.index(of: self)!
        let previous = all.index(before: idx)
        return all[previous < all.startIndex ? all.index(before: all.endIndex) : previous]
    }

    func next() -> Self {
        let all = Self.allCases
        let idx = all.index(of: self)!
        let next = all.index(after: idx)
        return all[next == all.endIndex ? all.startIndex : next]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually you don't need `BidirectionalCollection` conformance to implement `previous` case as well.

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    
    func previous() -> Self {
        let all = Self.allCases
        var idx = all.firstIndex(of: self)!
        if idx == all.startIndex {
            let lastIndex = all.index(all.endIndex, offsetBy: -1)
            return all[lastIndex]
        } else {
            all.formIndex(&idx, offsetBy: -1)
            return all[idx]
        }
    }

    func next() -> Self {
        let all = Self.allCases
        let idx = all.firstIndex(of: self)!
        let next = all.index(after: idx)
        return all[next == all.endIndex ? all.startIndex : next]
    }
    
}
```

You can also make a more generic cyclic offset function:

```
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable  {
    func advanced(by n: Int) -> Self {
        let all = Array(Self.allCases)
        let idx = (all.firstIndex(of: self)! + n) % all.count
        print(idx)
        if idx >= 0 {
            return all[idx]
        } else {
            return all[all.count + idx]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: upvoted because this is much cleaner code. less duplication. next and prev can call advanced.

Answer (score 0):

## 2022

We can create extension:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript (infinityIdx idx: Index) -> Element where Index == Int {
        return self[ idx % self.count ]
    }
}
```

lets try this ext in action:

```
enum SomeEnum: CaseIterable {
    case v1, v2, v3, v4
}

for i in 0...15 {
    print(SomeEnum.allCases[infinityIdx: i] )
}
```

result:

```
v1
v2
v3
v4
v1
v2
v3
v4
v1
v2
v3
```