# Swift: Index of an element in enum (CaseIterable)

Tags: swift, enums

The following code (compiles without errors) retrieves index of an element
in a particular CaseIterable enum type

```
public enum MyEnum : CaseIterable {
    case ONE, TWO, THREE

    public func ordinal() -> Int? {
       return MyEnum.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)
    }
}
```

I want to make a generic function to work with all CaseIterable enums.

If I try:

```
 public extension CaseIterable {

    public func ordinal() -> Int? {
        return CaseIterable.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)
    }
 }
```

I get a compiler error "`Member 'allCases' cannot be used on value of protocol type 'CaseIterable'; use a generic constraint instead`" which is quite logical, as the actual enum type is unknown".

When I try `CaseIterable<T>`, I get another error, as CaseIterable is not declared as generic type.

Is there a way?

Comment: Related: [How to get next case of enum(i.e. write a circulating method) in Swift 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51103795/1187415)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Couple of changes are necessary:

1. The return type needs to be `Self.AllCases.Index?` rather than `Int?`. In practice, these types will be equivalent, as seen below.
2. You also need to constrain any types to `Equatable`, because you need to be equatable in order to use `firstIndex(of:)`. Again, in practice, any `CaseIterable` will usually be an enum without associated values, meaning it will be equatable automatically.
3. (Optional change) This function will never return `nil`, because you're finding one case in a `CaseIterable`. So you can remove the optionality on the return type (`Self.AllCases.Index`) and force unwrap.

Example:

```
public extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {

    public func ordinal() -> Self.AllCases.Index {
        return Self.allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!
    }

}

enum Example: CaseIterable {

    case x
    case y

}

Example.y.ordinal()  // 1
type(of: Example.y.ordinal()) // Int
```

Personally, I'd add that "Ordinal" usually means something different than what you're doing, and I'd recommend changing the function name to `elementIndex()` or something. But that's an aside.

Comment: That was really fast!

Comment: And you can an non optional value and force unwrap it. This will never return nil

Comment: Ah good point. I tunnel visioned on the actual problem and forgot it was CaseIterable.

Comment: What about `hashValue`?

Comment: @えるまる What about it? If you want `Example` to have a `hashValue`, you can separately conform to `Hashable`: `enum Example: CaseIterable, Hashable`

Comment: hashValue returns position of case in enum