# Swift enum previous and next values

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have a following Swift enum:

```
 public enum Scale: Int, CaseIterable, Comparable {

  case scale1, scale2, scale3, scale4, scale5, scale6, scale7, scale8, scale9, scale10

   public static func < (lhs: RulerScale, rhs: RulerScale) -> Bool {
      return lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
   }

   private var nextScale:Scale {
     var nextScale = self
    
     for scale in Scale.allCases.reversed() {
         if scale > nextScale {
             nextScale = scale
         }
     }
    
     return nextScale
   }

   public var previousScale:Scale {
       var prevScale = self
    
        for scale in Scale.allCases {
           if scale < self {
              prevScale = scale
          }
        }
    
       return prevScale
   }

}
```

I wrote the code to identify previous and next case elements but not sure if there is an easier way that is built within the language to find the previous and next case elements, and whether what I have written is guaranteed to be correct across all Swift versions and compilers.

Comment: Have a look at [How to get next case of enum(i.e. write a circulating method) in Swift 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51103795/1187415).

Comment: are your cases literally `scale1`, `scale2` etc? if so, why do you need an enum at all? You could do something like `let scale: CountableClosedRange = 1...10` (for example, depends, what's it actually needed for)

Comment: Well, there are methods defined specific to each scale size and there is interdependency among them. For instance, scale1 may have 1 division but scale 2 will have 5 divisions and scale 2 length is twice of scale 1, etc.